# Can't access to my spring boot application pages

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web-applications

I create my spring boot application, i don't know why, but i can not access to my views, i think probably that the problem is with the spring boot resolver.

//My Controller

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/dataSource/creation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage() {
    System.out.println("checked here");
    return "home";
}
}
```

// The configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DataIntegratorSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
}

@Configuration
public class DataIntegratorConfiguration {

@Bean(name = "DataSourceMetadataCache")
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSourceMetadata> cache() {
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSourceMetadata>();
}

@Bean(name = "jmsRequestResponseCache")
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, JMSExchange> jmsReqResCache() {
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JMSExchange>();
}
}
```

// pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId> </groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

**Error :**

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Jun 23 12:14:45 WET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Not Found

Comment: What URL are you accessing?

Comment: @ledniov http://localhost:8181/api/v1/dataSource/creation

Comment: Is @EnableAutoConfiguration in the main configuration? and if so, have you try to specify the package with @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "your.package" })?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any template engine. Add `spring-boot-thymeleaf-starter` dependency and Spring Boot will configure view resolvers for you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it works, but i wouldn't use thymeleaf in my application, otherwise how can i fix it ?

Comment: @AnassAzzeddine what template engine are you planning to work with? If you want to be able to return view names from your controller - you have to use template engine, otherwise, you'll need to make your controller return response body instead of redirecting to view.

Comment: @AnassAzzeddine in order to access for a simple `index.html` file you have to put it into `static` folder.